# How to assign tasks in Bugzilla?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, bug-tracking, bugzilla, mylyn

i intend to use bugzilla eclipse plugin for collaborating in my project
we are a team working together in one project
and i was wondering how can i assign task to another colleague in the project using bugzilla
please guide me since, tutorials are very brief.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browse to the issue, type in your colleague's email in the Assignee field, click Save Changes.